# How secure are log files?

Tags: linux, logs

I wonder if I can believe log files. How secure are log files in *nix? If compared to Windows and OSX, is Linux better in securing log files? Any chance of log files have been modified without any trace at all?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with root access can modify log files.  Even if the logfile has an `append-only` attribute (e.g. with `chattr +a`) root can remove that attribute, modify the file, and then add the append-only attribute back to the file.

If you are worried about a local user with root access (e.g. via `sudo`) or a cracker modifying your log files, you can configure `syslogd` to send some or all of your syslog entries to another host.  Of course, if they also have or gain access to your remote logging host then they can modify the files there too (this is why loghosts tend to be highly secured).

Non-root users can only modify log files if the permissions on the file allow them to.  On a correctly configured system, they can't.  For some log files (e.g. `/var/log/auth.log`), they shouldn't even be able to read them.